# Redhisft SQL subquery uses ungrouped column from outer query

Tags: sql, date, select, subquery, amazon-redshift

I am getting the following error when trying to do a subquery **subquery uses ungrouped column "s.event_captured_dt" from outer query**

```
select

to_date(s.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY')
,count(*) as count_
,(select count(*) 
    from spc_raw_responsys_kanui.sent s1
    where to_date(s1.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') between to_date(s.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') - 7 and to_date(s.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY')
) as count7days_
    
from spc_raw_responsys_kanui.sent s

where 1=1 
and to_date(s.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') >= '2020-06-01 00:00:00'

group by to_date(s.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY')
```

That s what I am trying to achieve:

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tx1k.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you pre-aggregate in a subquery?

```
select
    s.*,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from spc_raw_responsys_kanui.sent s1
        where to_date(s1.event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') 
            between s.event_captured_date - 7 
            and s.event_captured_date
    ) as count7days_
from (
    select to_date(event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') event_captured_date, count(*) as count_
    from spc_raw_responsys_kanui.sent s
    where to_date(event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY') >= '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    group by to_date(event_captured_dt,'DD Mon YYYY')
) s
```

Comment: Yeah, worked !
But I guess its not performing so well. Tooke me 2min to run it.

Comment: Any other option, or should I leave this way ?

Comment: @MiguelFilho: pre-aggregation is better from performance perspective. The performance issue is another problem, that is related to the subquery. As a starter, you should consider storing dates as dates rather than strings. Then, you can remove all `to_date()` calls, and create an index on column `event_captured_dt`.